# In Django templates, firstof or default?

Tags: django, django-templates

Do these two commands have the same functionality in Django templates?

```
{{ foo|default:"bar" }}
```

and

```
{% firstof foo "bar" %}
```

If these work in the same way, then what are the best practices? Use `firstof` only if we have more than 2 arguments, or always use `firstof`?

Comment: Be careful when using `firstof`, it does not escape its output (this is changing in Django 1.6).

Answer (score 3):

`default` can be considered a specialized case of `firstof`.

[`firstof`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) outputs the first variable that is not `False` - Think of the `or` clause - it evaluates until any one of the objects evaluate to `True` and returns that.

It can be used to compare multiple values, whereas `default` is used for a specific object.

[`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default) outputs the specified default value if the object evaluates to `False`

Comment: `firstof` isn't like the `any` function. `any` returns True/False, `firstof` will return the unescaped value of the first variable that doesn't exquate to `False`